USB STM32 implementation without using HAL - not receiving get configuration descriptor
I am trying to implement a basic USB-OTG FS device without the use of the HAL library (for the usb part, for everything else, HAL is allowed, such is the school assignment specification). I am using the STM3240G-EVAL board, which has a stm32f407 core.
So far, I have been able to implement receiving of setup packets, sending of the device descriptor, and receiving of the set_address command. After these, the configuration descriptor request should follow in the enumeration process, but I am not receiving it, and I've run out of ideas on what may be the cause. All I receive are more get_descriptor requests for the device descriptor.
I have verified (using the dmesg command, and through wireshark), that the device descriptor is delivered properly, and that the zero-length packet, which confirms the receiving of the address, are both delivered to the host fine. Since the setting of the address is just followed by another device descriptor request, All this indicates that I am not setting the address right, but I do not believe that to be the case, I have checked that many times. The documentation is fairly sparse in answers to this problem. Below is the code I am using, assuming the usb_init() function is called in main.c.
If I comment-out the sending of the zero-length packet in the set_address function, the dmesg then responds with the device not accepting address, which leads me to believe, that the communication with the host works fine.
The clocks have been configured according to a template we've been given, so I do not think there would be a problem.
I am aware of this issue, but that uses a different core, that does not seem to use the same USB peripheral in the core, so I haven't found much help there.
There are a couple things I am not shure if they are correct:

The wLength field in the get_descriptor for the device descriptor has value of 64. I would exepect 18, since that is the size of the device descriptor, but I have also found, that hosts like to request the maximum packet size full-speed usb can handle, and just read what arrives, so I think this is fine.

The get_descriptor requests arrive two. I receive the first one, respond with the device descriptor, then I get another one, respond again, and then a single set_address command arrives. But again, I can imagine, that this is acceptable as normal USB behavior.


This is the code used for interrupt handling:
uint8_t address_pending = 0;
uint16_t address;
setup_packet_t setup = {0};

device_descriptor_t usb_device_descriptor = {
    .bLength = 18,
    .bDescriptorType = USB_DESCRIPTOR_DEVICE,
    .bcdUSB = USB_BCD_2,
    .bDeviceClass = USB_CDC_CLASS,
    .bDeviceSubClass = USB_CDC_ACM_SUBCLASS,
    .bDeviceProtocol = USB_NO_SPECIFIC_PROTOCOL,
    .bMaxPacketSize0 = 64,
    .idVendor = 0x0483,
    .idProduct = 0x5740,
    .bcdDevice = 0x0100,
    .iManufacturer = 0,
    .iProduct = 0,
    .iSerialNumber = 0,
    .bNumConfigurations = 1,
};

void usb_reset_handler() {
     USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_OUT->DOEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DOEPCTL_SNAK  ; // set the NAK bit for end-point 0

    // interrupt un-masking
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV->DAINTMSK |= USB_OTG_DAINTMSK_IEPM | USB_OTG_DAINTMSK_OEPM;
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV->DOEPMSK |= USB_OTG_DOEPMSK_STUPM | USB_OTG_DOEPMSK_XFRCM;
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV->DIEPMSK |= USB_OTG_DIEPMSK_XFRCM;

    USB_OTG_FS->GRXFSIZ = RX_FIFO_DEPTH_IN_WORDS; // size of RxFIFO (arbitrarily chosen)
    USB_OTG_FS->DIEPTXF0_HNPTXFSIZ = (TX_FIFO_DEPTH_IN_WORDS << USB_OTG_TX0FD_Pos) | RX_FIFO_DEPTH_IN_WORDS; // size of TxFIFO, address of txFifo
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_OUT->DOEPTSIZ = (1 << USB_OTG_DOEPTSIZ_STUPCNT_Pos) | (1 << USB_OTG_DOEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Pos) | 8; // receive 1 setup packet, 1 packet, 8 bytes
}

void usb_enum_done_handler() {
    uint32_t enum_speed = (USB_OTG_FS_DEV->DSTS & 0x6) >> 1; // read the enumerated speed

    if (enum_speed == 3) {
        USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_IN->DIEPCTL &= 0x00; // set packet size to 64 bytes
    } else {
        // error probably
        while(1);
    }
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_OUT->DOEPCTL |= 0x00 | USB_OTG_DOEPCTL_EPENA | USB_OTG_DOEPCTL_CNAK;
}

void read_setup() {
    uint32_t* buffer = (uint32_t*) &setup;

    for (uint16_t idx = 0; idx < 2; idx++, buffer++) {
        *buffer = *USB_OTG_FS_ENDPOINT0_FIFO;
    }
}

void write_FIFO(const void *data, uint32_t byte_length) {
    uint8_t* tx_buffer = (uint8_t *)data;
    uint32_t word_length = (byte_length + 3)/4;
    if (word_length > TX_FIFO_DEPTH_IN_WORDS) {
        while(1); // unable to write moar data than fifo size
    }
    while (USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_IN->DTXFSTS < word_length); // wait for TxFIFO to make room for message

    // USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_IN->DIEPINT |= USB_OTG_DIEPINT_INEPNE;
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_IN->DIEPTSIZ = (1 << USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Pos) | byte_length;
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_IN->DIEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_EPENA | USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_CNAK; // enable data transmit, clear NAK

    for (int i = 0; i < word_length; i += 1) {
        *USB_OTG_FS_ENDPOINT0_FIFO = __UNALIGNED_UINT32_READ(tx_buffer);
        tx_buffer++;
        tx_buffer++;
        tx_buffer++;
        tx_buffer++;
    }
}

void usb_read_data() {
    USB_OTG_FS->GINTMSK &= ~USB_OTG_GINTMSK_RXFLVLM; // ban further interrupts of this kind

    uint32_t otg_status = USB_OTG_FS->GRXSTSP;
    uint32_t endpoint_number = otg_status & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_EPNUM;
    uint32_t byte_count = (otg_status & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT) >> USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT_Pos;
    uint32_t data_pid = (otg_status & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_DPID) >> USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_DPID_Pos;
    uint32_t packet_status = (otg_status & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_PKTSTS) >> USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_PKTSTS_Pos;

    switch (packet_status) {
        case PCKT_STS_SETUP:
            if (endpoint_number != 0 || byte_count != 8) {
                while(1);
            }
            read_setup();
            break;
        case PCKT_STS_SETUP_COMPLETE:
            break;
        default:
            while(1);
    }

    USB_OTG_FS->GINTMSK |= USB_OTG_GINTMSK_RXFLVLM; // re-enable the RXFLVL interrupt
}

void set_address(uint16_t new_address) {
    address = new_address;
    address_pending = 1;
    write_FIFO(0, 0);
}

void setup_device_to_host() {
    if (setup.bRequest == BREQUEST_GET_DESCRIPTOR) {
        switch ((setup.wValue & 0xf00) >> 8) { // extract descriptor type
            case USB_DESCRIPTOR_DEVICE:
                if (setup.wLength > 18) {
                    write_FIFO(&usb_device_descriptor, 18);
                } else {
                    write_FIFO(&usb_device_descriptor, setup.wLength);
                }
                break;
            case USB_DESCRIPTOR_CONFIGURATION:
                break;
            case USB_DESCRIPTOR_STRING:
                break;
            case USB_DESCRIPTOR_INTERFACE:
                break;
            case USB_DESCRIPTOR_ENDPOINT:
                break;
            default:
                while (1);
        }

    } else if (setup.bRequest == BREQUEST_GET_STATUS) {
        uint16_t status = USB_STATUS_RESPONSE;
        write_FIFO(&status, 2);
    }

}

void setup_host_to_device() {
    if (setup.bRequest == BREQUEST_SET_ADDRESS) {
        set_address(setup.wValue);
    } else {
        while(1);
    }
}

void usb_handle_setup_packet() {
    if (setup.bmRequestType & 0x80) {
        setup_device_to_host();
    } else {
        setup_host_to_device();
    }
}

void usb_interrupt_out_handler() {
    if (USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_OUT->DOEPINT & USB_OTG_DOEPINT_STUP) {
        USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_OUT->DOEPINT |= USB_OTG_DOEPINT_STUP;
        usb_handle_setup_packet();
    } else {
        while(1);
    }
}

void usb_interrupt_in_handler() {
    if (USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_IN->DIEPINT & USB_OTG_DIEPINT_XFRC) {
        // transfer finished interrupt
        if (address_pending) {
            USB_OTG_FS_DEV->DCFG &= ~USB_OTG_DCFG_DAD;
            USB_OTG_FS_DEV->DCFG |= (address << USB_OTG_DCFG_DAD_Pos);
            address_pending = 0;
        }
        USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_IN->DIEPINT |= USB_OTG_DIEPINT_XFRC; // clear interrupt
    }
}

/** Wrapper for the individual interrupt handler functions
 * Called in stm32f4xx_it.c OTG_FS_IRQHandler, which is wired to be the interrupt handler for all OTG FS interrupt requests
 * Said wiring is done in the startup_stm32f407ighx.s startup assembly file */
void usb_IRQ_Handler() {
    if (USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS & USB_OTG_GINTSTS_USBRST) {
        USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS |= USB_OTG_GINTSTS_USBRST;
        usb_reset_handler();
    }
    if (USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS & USB_OTG_GINTSTS_ENUMDNE) {
        USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS |= USB_OTG_GINTSTS_ENUMDNE;
        usb_enum_done_handler();
    }
    if (USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS & USB_OTG_GINTSTS_RXFLVL) {
        // USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS |= USB_OTG_GINTSTS_RXFLVL;
        usb_read_data();
    }
    if (USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS & USB_OTG_GINTSTS_OEPINT) {
        USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS |= USB_OTG_GINTSTS_OEPINT;
        usb_interrupt_out_handler();
    }
    if (USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS & USB_OTG_GINTSTS_IEPINT) {
        USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS |= USB_OTG_GINTSTS_IEPINT;
        usb_interrupt_in_handler();
    }
}

Here is the usb peripheral initialization:
void usb_clock_enable() {
    __HAL_RCC_USB_OTG_FS_CLK_ENABLE();
}

void usb_core_init() {
    USB_OTG_FS->GCCFG |= USB_OTG_GCCFG_PWRDWN; // enable USB transceiver
    USB_OTG_FS->GAHBCFG |= USB_OTG_GAHBCFG_GINT | USB_OTG_GAHBCFG_PTXFELVL | USB_OTG_GAHBCFG_TXFELVL;

    USB_OTG_FS->GUSBCFG |= USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_TOCAL_0 | USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_TOCAL_1 | USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_TOCAL_2; // add clock cycles inter-packet timeout (based on manual in MOODLE)
    USB_OTG_FS->GUSBCFG |= USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_TRDT_0 |USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_TRDT_1 | USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_TRDT_2; // set USB turn-around time to 15 (based on formula in reference manual)

    USB_OTG_FS->GINTMSK |= USB_OTG_GINTMSK_OTGINT | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_MMISM; // un-mask global interrupt and mode mismatch interrupt

    // force device mode if in host mode
    if (USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS & USB_OTG_GINTSTS_CMOD) {
        USB_OTG_FS->GUSBCFG |= USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_FDMOD;
        USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS |= USB_OTG_GINTSTS_SOF | USB_OTG_GINTSTS_CIDSCHG;
        while (USB_OTG_FS->GINTSTS & USB_OTG_GINTSTS_CMOD);
    }
}


/** Initialize the peripheral as device (not as host) */
void usb_device_init() {
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV->DCFG |= USB_OTG_DCFG_DSPD_0 | USB_OTG_DCFG_DSPD_1; // set device speed to full-speed
    USB_OTG_FS_DEV->DCFG |= USB_OTG_DCFG_NZLSOHSK; // send a STALL packet on non-zero-length status OUT transaction (default USB behavior)

    USB_OTG_FS->GINTMSK |= USB_OTG_GINTMSK_USBRST | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_ENUMDNEM | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_RXFLVLM; // unmask interrupts
    USB_OTG_FS->GCCFG |= USB_OTG_GCCFG_VBUSBSEN; // enable V_BUS sensing "B"
}

/** Enable interrupts in the NVIC for USB OTG FS peripheral */
void usb_interrupt_init() {
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(OTG_FS_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(OTG_FS_IRQn);
}

void usb_gpio_init() {

      __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

      GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_11;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF10_OTG_FS;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF10_OTG_FS;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/** Wrapper for all the init functions */
void usb_init() {
    usb_gpio_init();
    usb_clock_enable();
    usb_core_init();
    usb_device_init();
    usb_interrupt_init();
}

Here is the code I use to access the FIFO, and the register definitions, along with the ued structs:
#define USB_OTG_FS_DEV    ((USB_OTG_DeviceTypeDef *) (USB_OTG_FS_PERIPH_BASE + USB_OTG_DEVICE_BASE))
#define USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_OUT     ((USB_OTG_OUTEndpointTypeDef *) (USB_OTG_FS_PERIPH_BASE + USB_OTG_OUT_ENDPOINT_BASE))
#define USB_OTG_FS_DEV_ENDPOINT0_IN  ((USB_OTG_INEndpointTypeDef *) (USB_OTG_FS_PERIPH_BASE + USB_OTG_IN_ENDPOINT_BASE))
#define USB_OTG_FS_ENDPOINT0_FIFO (volatile uint32_t*)(USB_OTG_FS_PERIPH_BASE + USB_OTG_FIFO_BASE)

typedef struct setup_packet_t {
    uint8_t bmRequestType;
    uint8_t bRequest;
    uint16_t wValue;
    uint16_t wIndex;
    uint16_t wLength;
} setup_packet_t;

typedef struct device_descriptor_t {
    uint8_t bLength;
    uint8_t bDescriptorType;
    uint16_t bcdUSB;
    uint8_t bDeviceClass;
    uint8_t bDeviceSubClass;
    uint8_t bDeviceProtocol;
    uint8_t bMaxPacketSize0;
    uint16_t idVendor;
    uint16_t idProduct;
    uint16_t bcdDevice;
    uint8_t iManufacturer;
    uint8_t iProduct;
    uint8_t iSerialNumber;
    uint8_t bNumConfigurations;
} device_descriptor_t;

As for the messages from dmesg, I am getting:
[13787.325818] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 118 using xhci_hcd
[13792.537186] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[13792.659138] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 119 using xhci_hcd
[13803.056238] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[13803.056409] usb usb3-port2: attempt power cycle
[13803.462977] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 120 using xhci_hcd
[13813.722852] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[13813.846183] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
[13824.176164] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[13824.176309] usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

The multiple attempts I assume are just the host re-trying the communication.
Thanks a lot for Your time!
EDIT 1:
I've done some digging, and looked at the wireshark communication. Here is what I've found:
wireshark comms
Here, the host first correctly resets the usb device, then requests the device descriptor. The response from my device can be seen on selected, I do not see anyting wrong, except for the leftover capture data. Furthermore, the host resets the device again, requests the device descriptor once more, this time requests 18 bytes, which are delivered fine. Also notice the address change, so on my side, the address is set properly. But then, instead of other requests, the usb port gets disabled and reset again, and the process starts over.
The leftover capture data are just padding or the response to match the 64 bytes requested, but I am not explicitly sending that (as you can see from the code), so there seems to be an issue with the short packet sending. But I do not think this to be the source of the issue, since then the communication continues fine.
The first and second device descriptor responses are identical in their contents.
EDIT 2:
As a kind stranger pointed out in the comments, the access to the buffer in the write_FIFO function, which is not aligned to 4byte words, is generally unsafe, but the standard CMSIS macro used in the reading of the buffer ensures safety of that read opearion.
EDIT 3:
Okay, I have no idea what changed, but the wireshrk result now looks different, now I the -71 error pops up on the side of the host instead of receiving the second device descriptor. The address I receive in the code (in what i've tested it was 3) does not match the address issued by the host, which was reported by dmesg to be 84, but I can't find the reason for the wrong delivery of the address. One would think the reading of the setup packet is wrong, but since I am able to decode the get_descriptor request, then the function for reading the FIFO would work fine. I will keep looking though.
EDIT 4:
The issue is now resolved. The problem was, that on receiving the device descriptor, the host responds with an ack in the form of a zero-length packet. And the usb peripheral needs the programmer to explicitly program the out endpoint to receive a zero-length packet, otherwise it starts sending NAKs. It worked in the case of the first device descriptor, because it is immediately followed by a reset, not by an ackonwledgement, so it failed only in the second delivery of the device descriptor.

You need to figure out why the kernel is printing messages like "device descriptor read/all, error -71".  In errno.h, we see that 71 is a "protocol error".  I would look in Wireshark and inspect the data that your device is sending in the device descriptor and make sure each byte matches what you expect it to be.  If there is a problem there, the USB host generally gives up on talking to the device.

Yeah, maybe your write_FIFO function needs to be fixed.  You're reading two bytes beyond the end of the device descriptor (since it's only 18 bytes and you are reading in 4-byte chunks) which would probably be undefined behavior in C.  Then you are sending those extra two bytes to the FIFO, so maybe that is transmitted to the host and causing it to get confused.  Note that after reading your device descriptor, the host immediately sends a request to the hub (NOT the device) to reset the USB port.  So your characterization that "communication continues fine" after the padding is incorrect.

Thank you for your response!
While You are right, that my write_FIFO function needs the fix You mentioned, I do not think that the communication is confusing the host right in the first device descriptor, since the host does issue an address, and later re-requests the device descriptor, as expected.
Furthermore, the Reset command is not visible to wireshark, since a USB reset is a physical layer operation, and not an explicit command sent in a setup packet.

I have also failed to mention, that 32bit access to the buffer, which is not aligned to 32bit words is safe thanks to the strange macro used in the write_FIFO function.

You say a Reset is not happening and that it's not visible on Wireshark, but I can see pretty clearly on line 64 of your wireshark screenshot that your computer is sending a "Set Feature" request to enable a PORT_RESET within a millisecond of asking for your device descriptor.  I'm not an expert in the USB hub protocol but the hub is probably sending a RESET signal on to your device.  So we need to see the details of line 63, including all the data that was transferred, so we can check it.
